# Powershell Excel Chart - obtain data series from existing chart

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, charts

I have a Powershell script that copies a worksheet (with a custom dual axis chart) from one workbook to another workbook and then populates the new copy with data. That portion of the script works fine but I am trying to change the data series in the existing chart and I do not know the fields to change the data series.

I can change the chart title and the legend labels of the existing chart with no issues. I have tried the `$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(1).Values` field and the `$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(1).XValues` with and with out the `$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection().NewSeries.Invoke()` command and I have had no success.

Does anyone know the Powershell syntax to edit an existing data series of a custom dual axis line chart (`=SERIES(Template!$G$1,Template!$A$2:$A$112,Template!$G$2:$G$112,4`) ?

The following is my Powershell code which I have obtained from googling:

```
$file1 = $global:ChartTemplateXlsx    # source's fullpath
$file2 = $Path                        # destination's fullpath
$xl = new-object -c excel.application 
$xl.Visible = $False                  # dont display the spreadsheet
$xl.displayAlerts = $false            # don't prompt the user
$wb1 = $xl.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true)   # open source, readonly
$wb = $xl.workbooks.open($file2)      # open target workbook/worksheet
$sh1_wb = $wb.sheets.item(1)          # 1st sheet in destination workbook
$sheetToCopy = $wb1.sheets.item('Template')   # source sheet to copy
$sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb)   # copy source sheet to destination workbook

$ws = $wb.ActiveSheet                        # set the worksheet

$ChartTemplate = $ws.chartobjects(1).chart   # obtain the existing chart
$ChartTemplate.HasTitle = $true              # turn on chart title
$ChartTemplate.ChartTitle.Text = "Test Chart" # set a new chart title

$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Test01"""
$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Test02"""
$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""Test03"""
$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""Test04"""

$wb1.close($false)               # close source workbook w/o saving
$wb.close($true)                 # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```

By the way, I am using a separate workbook with the chart so that users can create their own chart templates and then I will populate it with data.

Answer (score 0):

The property that you're looking for is either the `Formula` or `FormulaLocal` property. They appear to be duplicates of each other. If updating one doesn't work, try the other, or just set both.

```
$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(1).Formula = '=SERIES(Template!$G$1,Template!$A$2:$A$112,Template!$G$2:$G$112,4)'
$ChartTemplate.SeriesCollection(1).FormulaLocal = '=SERIES(Template!$G$1,Template!$A$2:$A$112,Template!$G$2:$G$112,4)'
```